# PhoneGap version's Support for Windows Phone 8

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8

I want to know which versions of Phonegap Windows 8 phones support. I googled a lot and found that versions 3.4.0 , 3.0.0, and 2.9.1 of Phonegap support WP8. But I want to know which other versions of Phonegap support Windows Phone 8.

Comment: Are u asking about phonegap or cordova versions?

Comment: i am asking for Phonegap versions.

Answer (score 0):

I have used phonegap/cordova 2.9 version and it is supported well on windows8 platform.